# Как узнать, кто использует базу данных?

Tags: mysql

Как точно узнать, кто использует MySQL базу данных, узнать ip-адреса всех использующих её серверов? Возможно ли это получить эту информацию относительного какого-то периода в прошлом, например, за предыдущий час?

Comment: Вот решение https://serverfault.com/questions/288015/mysql-log-every-connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переименовать базу и посмотреть, кто будет ругаться :)

В MySQL, насколько я знаю, такого логирования не ведется. Но можно узнать, кто подключен к базе в данный момент

```
SELECT
  proc.`host`
FROM
  information_schema.processlist proc
WHERE
  proc.`db` = 'mydb'
```

поэтому, одно из решений задачи - выполнять этот запрос периодически каким-нибудь шедулером (в том числе и встроенным) и складывать в лог-таблицу результаты.

Минус подхода - можно пропустить короткоживущие подключения.